# What is the difference between these two variable definitions?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm relatively new to c++ and have been thrown into the deep end in a particularly large existing project. During some work, I've come across a piece of code that causes a segfault:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foobar> foo = boost::shared_ptr<Foobar>(new Foobar(bar));
```

With an error like:

```
#0  shared_count (r=..., this=0xb2e265c4) at .../boost/include/boost-1_55/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:382
    382 .../boost/include/boost-1_55/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp: No such file or directory.
    in .../boost/include/boost-1_55/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp
#1  shared_ptr (this=0xb2e265c0) at .../boost/include/boost-1_55/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:329
#2  FooHandler::doAThing (this=0xb2e27310) at .../fooHandler.cpp:42
```

However, when I change it to this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foobar> foo;
foo = boost::shared_ptr<Foobar>(new Foobar(bar));
```

It works perfectly fine.

---

My question is, is there some difference between defining the variable `foo` by itself, and defining it at the same time as assigning a value to it, that could cause this kind of issue?

Comment: This sounds like a race condition of some sort, which is system-specific. Unfortunately, such an question is unanswerable without an isolated example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The difference is the latter is assignment, the former is [intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). No idea if that will help you or not. And fyi, consider using [`boost::make_shared`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html) for making compressed shared pointers if possible.

Comment: With the available information this is hard to debug. Might as well be a stack corruption due to undefined behavior somewhere else in the code.